# How can multiple datasources be managed by a single ViewModel in a UWP app along with design-time binding?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp, viewmodel

I am having a hard time finding out how to blend multiple data sources into a UWP page's ViewModel.    I have several models which have the C# Classes defines for my objects that correspond to a Json data source.

It's fairly straight forward to have a 1:1 mapping of my UI/View ==> ViewModel ==> Data Model/DataSource.   But how can I do this, have a single ViewModel which is populated by multiple data models?   I have a master/detail type of project and on the detail page there are controls that need to be bound to several data sources and are mixed together in various containers like a Grid and StackPanel.
I also want to use Binding rather than x:Bind so I can focus on the UX design with design-time data populated by sample data from my data models.
Rather than have to mix DataContexts from several data sources on the detail page, how could I populate a blended ViewModel with sample data from more than one data source?

Would anyone be able to outline a simple example of 2 data models that are populated on creation with sample data, then that data is populated in the joint ViewModel to be leveraged by a XAML page with design-time using Binding data based on the combination of those data properties?

I'm looking to do this because the services I am calling have APIs that return different responses of hierarchical data that are related and its often useful to mix together related data on a single detail page to provide all of the relevant information.

I hope I explained that well enough, let me know if I need to clarify it further.

Thanks,
 Rick

Comment: Any issues if you put these data sources as sub resources of one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: The [master/details sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/how-to-bind-to-hierarchical-data-and-create-a-master-details-view)  just contains several data models, not only one. So I'm not sure what issue you actually met since you don't have any code snippet to help describe your issues. And what the XAML controls you are using for binding data?